# Difference between loc, iloc, apply?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, apply, pandas-loc

Could you describe me the difference between: loc, iloc and apply ? Preferably based on examples.
`df.loc`
`df.iloc`
`df.apply()`

Comment: `loc` and `iloc` are used for indexing of the data in a dataframe. `df.apply` as name says is used to apply a function on the dataframe. It returns a series or dataframe based on the function you want to apply.

Comment: See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc), [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please see [ask].  It is against the guidelines to ask open ended questions such as these.  I'd suggest reading the documentation as provided by @iuvbio and going through the many tutorials/samples online.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are used in pandas for the purpose of **Row Selection**.
.iloc : Selecting data according to the **row number**.
.loc : Selecting data on basis of the **label name** or by using any **conditional statement**.